# Why is language in Bot framework changed automatically?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am using Bot framework as direct line implementation. Bot is using two languages: "en" and "nl". I am setting the language as shown:

```
if(somecondition)
{
    locale = "nl";         
    session.preferredLocale(locale);  
    var text = session.localizer.gettext(locale,"pastErrorText");
    session.send(text);
} else {
    locale = "en";           
    session.preferredLocale(locale);  
    var text = session.localizer.gettext(locale,"pastErrorText");
    session.send(text);
}
```

Lets say i am using bot in en (English). When I use the bot suddenly the language is getting switched to nl (Dutch) in between the conversation, even though the conditions are not met. It also happens vice versa.

What might be the issue? Is it something with cache, if multiple users are using it simultaneously? Is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: Where does this code you've shared reside?  ... This example provides some direction for allowing users to choose a language: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples/basics-libraries

Comment: The code I have shared resides in the nodejs application.I am passing the language "NL" or "EN" from the client (browser/ the webpage where the js bot is added) via event to the chatbot.

Comment: Yes, but WHERE in the node.js application is the code you've shared?  There isn't enough code here to reproduce the issue you're having, or suggest a fix.  Please share more code, so we can help.

Comment: Yes, in a node application ... however, I'm asking for the code surrounding what you have posted here.  This is not enough to determine what is going wrong.  Please share more of your bot's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TextTranslator API.